# Multiple table in word using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

How can i add multiple table in word document using apache poi in java. Table1(2 column, 4 rows) and table2(3 column, 4 rows).  Iam a beginner...

Comment: No one is there to help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you create a paragraph? Have you looked at the examples and the API docs? You are probably not being helped because you said "Pls give me the code."

Comment: Ok. I have created first table(4r,2c), below this table i want to write some more lines or a paragraph. Everything work fine. But the real problem when I created the second table(4r,3c).

Comment: Show us your code, and tell us what the problem is. Are you getting errors? What are they? You should be able to add as many paragraphs and tables as you want. and Tables can even be nested inside of tables.